# Errorhandling using express.csrf()

Tags: node.js, express

I have some Questions about using CSRF protection. When I use a "post" route without a valid csrf-token i get a "Error: Forbidden at Object.exports.error ....", Is it possible to redirect request without a valid token to a special route?

Here is my code:

```
app.use(express.csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
    res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();  
    next();  
});
```

Another question is, whats a good way to protect this token? Is it better to store it in a cookie, instead using a hidden field? Or isn't there any difference reffering to the security?

```
form(method="post",action="/test")  
    input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value="#{csrftoken}")
```

Third Questions is: Users with disabled cookies can't access any routes, right? So can i use the protection only for special routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes. You can use

```
res.redirect('/redirect_route');
```

see http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.redirect

2) I thing cookie or hidden field is not secure at all, you can use what you like

3) Yes. You can use middleware to protect special routes

```
app.get('/account', checkToken, routes.account);

function checkUser(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken();  
    next(); 
}
```

Comment: thank you! what about users with disabled cookies? And how do I use the redirect to fire on Error: Forbidden?

Comment: for error handling you can use error middleware. pls see Error handling section http://stephensugden.com/middleware_guide/. Error middleware has 4 function parameters and will be handled anyway. Just check 403 error and redirect user where you whant. For disabled cookies use hidden fields :)

Comment: hmm...but the csrf token is saved in the session, and only can found by a session id? withput cookies, there isnt a id?