# NodeJS Express CSRF Error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, csrf

I am receiving the following stack trace error from my Node server.  My app runs on Angular and uses Node to interact with the API.

```
Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (/home/bitnami/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (/home/bitnami/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
at /home/bitnami/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:54:7
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bitnami/myapp/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/uid2/index.js:46:8)
at Object.ondone (/home/bitnami/myapp/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
```

Here is how my Express app is configured:

```
app = express()
app.configure ->
  app.use express.static(__dirname + "/_public")
  app.use (req, res) ->
    res.sendfile __dirname + assetUrl + "/index.html"
  app.use express.logger("dev")
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.cookieParser("shhhh, very secret")
  app.use express.cookieSession()
  app.use express.csrf(value: csrfValue)
  app.use (req, res, next) ->
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken())
    res.locals.csrftoken = req.csrfToken()
    next()
  app.use app.router
```

And here is the client side code:

HTML:

```
<form name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm(loginForm)">
  <label for="username">Email</label>
  <input id="username" type="email" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required placeholder="Enter your email address">

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" required placeholder="Enter your password" ng-minlenth="7">

  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Javascript (Angular):

```
login = (info) ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    $http(
      method: 'POST'
      url: '/auth/login'
      data: info
    ).then ((resp) ->
      userInfo = resp.data.data
      $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo)
      deferred.resolve userInfo
    ), (error) ->
      $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = null
      deferred.reject error
      return
```

I believe this is the culprit to why the communication between Node and the API goes down.  The issue only happens when trying to log in again in AFTER logging out.  Does this have to do with how Angular loads pages?  If I refresh the page, the issue doe not occur.

Comment: show some client code pls

Comment: @xShirase updated the snippets above

Comment: it has to do with the XSRF token. I'm guessing that it is erased when you log out, but I've never used this so I can't tell you more. Verify that you have a valid token when you make your request

Comment: What does `csrfValue()` look like?

Comment: @xShirase how do I verify if a token is valid?

Comment: check first that it has a value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errorhandling using express.csrf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864998/errorhandling-using-express-csrf)